# alert the associated option values and text by index

Tags: jquery

I am trying to alert the index, value, and text in an alert.

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#idea_store_ids').chosen().change(function(){
      var doai = $(".search-choice-close").map(function(){
      return $(this).attr("data-option-array-index");}
  ).get();
  $.each(doai , function(index, value) { 
    var storename = $("#idea_store_ids option").map(function() {
             return $(this).text();
          }).get();
    alert(index + ": " + value + ": " + storename); 
  });
  });
});
```

But I am having a hard time getting only the associated option name to display. It displays all of them. I think it is because there is nothing relating #idea_store_ids option and "data-option-array-index" to know which belongs to what. So I am wondering if its a good idea to index both selectors and associated them that way.

How might I do that?

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="idea[store_ids][]"></input>
<select id="idea_store_ids" name="idea[store_ids][]" multiple="multiple" style="display: 
none;">

<option value="103">4 Wheeling Shirts-To-Go</option>
<option value="79">Aliens & Paranormal Shirts-To-Go</option>
<option value="63">America Shirts-To-Go</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Ann Arbor T-shirt Company</option>
<option value="19">Area Code Shirts To Go</option>....


<ul class="chosen-choices">
<li class="search-choice">
    <span> … </span>
    <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="3"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Is `.chosen()` from a plugin? There is no native chosen event.

Comment: yes it is for a plugin

Answer (score 0):

i think chosen rebuilds your structure so your map functions return no information, you can debug that with

`console.dir(doai)`

for example on chrome and ff you can see that no value is returned, watch with an element inspector how chosen rebuilds the markup i think it even has its own eventlistener for changing input

try to get the selected values like:

```
    var  storename = $.map( $(this).find("option:selected").val(), function(n){
          return this.value;
   });
```

Comment: are you saying to replace the storename variable with this? i tried that and the entire code brakes. where would console.dir(doai) go?

Comment: console.dir goes right behind the semicolon behind the declaration of var doai= xyz ; <-

Answer (score 0):

Just do this inside your `change`

```
alert(this.selectedIndex + ": " + this.value + ": " + $(this).find("option:selected").text());
```

Or:

```
var index = this.selectedIndex,
    value = this.value,
    text  = $(this).find("option:selected").text();

alert(index + ":" + value + ":" + text);
```